# Can organization access an email account they provided, if they don't know your password?

Tags: email, user-accounts, privacy

Can a school access an email account they provided you even though they don't know your password?

Comment: Yes. The school owns the account and can access the data in it via any of several means. Whether they WANT to our have the resources to is a better question that may help you more. It is the same for an employer as well. They pay for and manage the account, they are able to set what is in it is if they wish.

Comment: @BlindSpots Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382821/355310 and don't introduce this problem while editing questions. Flag this comment for removal ("no longer needed") after you read it.

Comment: Technically they can. But if you meant legally then this the wrong site.

Comment: https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/can-employer-read-email-personal-account.html

Comment: It may be a legitimate question, but is SU the place to ask is more the question.

Comment: It depends on the specific mail system being used (Outlook, Gmail, Hotmail, local on-premises, etc) but likely the answer is yes.

Comment: Depending on the country you are in, this may vary though. Here in Germany for example it is not allowed to look into someone's inbox according to our data protection laws. An employer can manage the account in all means possible except for reading the content of messages.

Answer (score 18):

Yes they can, though the method used may depend on the type of email system being used.

As an example though, if the email is on Exchange / 365 then the email admin could grant Full Access permissions on a specified mailbox to another user, after which they could access that mailbox using their own email login credentials, and not need to know the credentials of the mailbox they're accessing. That might be done for "monitoring" purposes, or simply organisational purposes, for instance a PA having access to their manager's mailbox so they can handle emails for their manager.

Other systems may not allow granting any old user access to a second mailbox, but may allow the admin to access it. For instance in a Linux/cPanel setup, the admin with access to the cPanel control panel can access any of the mailboxes configured on that server via the control panel, without needing to know the password of that mailbox as they're doing so as admin.

Comment: And essentially any system with an admin in the loop allows setting a new password - but you'd know about that when you got locked out.

Comment: Even if the organization doesn't know some password, they usually don't need it, they have multiple means to access the data, this depends on how security is managed. The basic access is built-in [vPro Intel chips](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/vpro-amt-management-kvm,3003-10.html).

Comment: @mins I don't see what remote control of a work station has to do with access to a mailbox?

Comment: @Bergi: If you can access the client workstation, then you don't need to enter any password, you let the user do it and just access what you want after the application has been unlocked (with the original application, or your own code), or you just look at the screen when the user displays their mail. That's only limited by the creativity of who uses the remote access. If you really want to retrieve a password, you just look at the keys pressed by the user, since you have full access to the keyboard, the screen and the mouse.

Comment: @mins That basically amounts to a keylogger and still requires the user to enter their password (which they might no longer do when they distrust the organisation). But that assumes the organisation would actually need to hack into the account, which is false - as this answer states and as you said yourself, "*the organization […] usually don't need [to know the password], they have multiple means to access the data*"

Comment: @Bergi: We are in agreement, I'm just adding that in the case you can't access the server database, or for other situations, serious organizations have full control of their computer fleet, even computers that are powered off (and for those without the "vPro" sticker, there are other possibilities, with some preparation).

Answer (score 0):

It is **BARELY POSSIBLE** to create a mail system where the mail is stored in encrypted form that the mail admin cannot access (but the legitimate user still could). Famous services like protonmail (pretend to) do it: the received mail is encrypted on arrival with the user's public key and **not stored in plain text form ***.

A mail system like this has a great deal of drawbacks - it is way harder to manage and debug than the traditional one, the search indexes of an encrypted content are somewhat tricky so no server-based search and so on. It also feels a constant pressure from the law enforcement, the state-backed hackers and the likes. It also attracts users with criminal background with all the consequences expected (and unexpected as well).

This is why an ordinary commercial or educational organization has no reason to maintain a service like this. All of them opt for the traditional mail service where the messages are stored in a plain text format either in a filesystem or in a database.  The mail confidentiality (where at all implied **) is maintained by the organizational means - the number of full-access admins is limited,
the admin actions are logged and audited, etc, etc...

There is a third approach in regard to the mail confidentiality - the approach of PGP and S/MIME-encrypted mails. In this case the sender sends the mail encrypted with the receiver's public key. In this case, all third-parties (including the mail services of both the sender and the receiver) could only know the sender, the receiver and the size of the message, but not the content.

This approach requires prior preparation of both sides, but has the advantage of being independent from the mail service in regard to privacy.

---

* this is a promise and not something enforced by externally verifiable technology means. They may break this promise at any time and the user will only know when it is way too late.

** In a lot of cases mail confidentiality is not implied at all. E.g. at my current workplace everyone can read everyone else's (the big boss included) mail and everyone does this on a regular basis in order to do their work. Anything not appropriate for this kind of "publicity" is either not work-related (a private mail should be used instead) or breaks some rule (and should not be sent/received in the first place).

Answer (score -6):

The idea that they don't know your password is wrong because a password protected account is protected with a [shared secret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_secret) between the two parties involved.

To protect user passwords from being easily seen and copied by intruders passwords are often saved not in clear text but in the form of a [hashed password](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password#Form_of_stored_passwords). But during the login process the shared password is always processed in a readable clear text form and can easily be logged. This is the reason why you should never use the same password for multiple accounts, because you don't want to share the same secret with more than one other party.

Other than that, emails on an email server are normal text files and can be read, processed and copied by the software systems involved and of course by the administrators managing those systems. If you want information you upload to servers to stay secret, you need to use good encryption.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147643/discussion-on-answer-by-xenoson-can-organization-access-an-email-account-they-pr); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.